# Bitmap getting every pixel not working properly using GetPixel()

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a program that will convert the Bitmap to array of 24bit hex color format.

But there is something wrong. Get Pixel is not working properly to get every pixel of a bitmap.

The images I load are only **32 x 32 pixels**

This is the code:

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();

   // image filters  
   open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
   if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // display image in picture box  
            pic.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
            // image file path  
            string picFile = open.FileName;

            //Make it to bitmap

            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(picFile);

            //Bitmap imgRes = ResizeImage(img, 30, 60);

            Bitmap imgRes = img;

            string[] arrayImage = new string[imgRes.Width * imgRes.Height];

            imgWidth.Text = imgRes.Width.ToString();
            imgHeight.Text = imgRes.Height.ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < imgRes.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < imgRes.Height; j++)
                {
                    Color pixel = imgRes.GetPixel(i, j);
                    arrayImage[i * j] = HexConverter(pixel).ToString();

                }
            }

            string hexFormat;

            hexFormat = arrayImage[0].ToString();

            for (int i = 1; i < arrayImage.Length; i++)
            {
                hexFormat = hexFormat + ", " + arrayImage[i];

            }

            //Paste it to text box
            hexFormat.Text = hexFormat;

        }

    //Color to HEX
    private static String HexConverter(System.Drawing.Color c)
    {
        return "0x" + c.R.ToString("X2") + c.G.ToString("X2") + c.B.ToString("X2");
    }
```

This is what I got:

**It is skipping pixels and NOT reading the first row of pixels. Also not accurate (see LCD Image Conversion)**

> 0x000000, 0x050505, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x020202, 0x010101, 0x030303,
>   0x020202, 0x0B0B0B, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0xFEFBA4, 0xFCFDED, 0xFCFDED,
>   0xFCFDED, 0xFCFDED, 0xFEFBA4, 0xFCFDED, 0xFEFBA4, 0xFCFDED, 0xF09F00,
>   0x653700, 0x613500, 0x101010, 0x020202, 0x030303, 0x010101, 0x000000,
>   0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0xFFFA73, 0xF09F00, 0xFFFA73,
>   0xFCFDED, 0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, 0xF09F00, 0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, ,
>   0xF09F00, 0xFFF402, 0x653700, , 0x633600, 0xFEFBA4, 0x050505,
>   0xF09F00, 0x000000, , 0x010101, 0x140100, 0x000000, 0xF09F00,
>   0x000000, , 0x000000, , 0x000000, 0xFFF402, 0xFFF402, 0x140100,
>   0xFFF402, , 0x140100, 0xFDCE00, 0xFFF402, , 0xF09F00, , , 0x653700,
>   0x140100, 0x140100, 0x0D0D0D, , 0xFFF402, 0x000000, , , 0x010101,
>   0x140100, , 0x000000, 0xFFF402, , 0x000000, 0x140100, 0xFFF402,
>   0x000000, , 0x140100, 0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, 0xFDCE00, 0xFFF402, ,
>   0x140100, , 0x643700, 0xFFF402, , , 0x090909, , 0xFFF402, , 0x010101,
>   , 0x140100, 0xFFF402, 0x010101, 0xFDCE00, , 0x140100, 0x000000,
>   0xFFF402, , , 0x000000, 0xFDCE00, 0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, ,
>   0xFFF402, 0x140100, , 0x653700, 0x140100, , 0xFFF402, , 0x0D0D0D, , ,
>   0xFFF402, 0xFFF402, 0x010101, , 0xFFF402, , , 0x000000, , 0x140100,
>   0xFDCE00, 0xFFF402, 0x000000, 0xFDCE00, , , , 0xFFF402, 0xFFF402,
>   0xFFF402, , , 0xFFF402, , , 0x653700, 0xFFF402, 0xFFF402, 0xFDCE00, ,
>   , 0x111111, 0xFFF402, 0xFFF402, , , , 0x010101, , 0xFDCE00, ,
>   0xFFF402, , 0x000000, 0xFFF402, , 0xFDCE00, 0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, , ,
>   0xFFF402, 0xF09F00, , 0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, , , 0x613500, 0xFFF402, ,
>   , 0xFFF402, 0xFDCE00, 0xFFF402, 0x020202, , , , , , 0xFDCE00,
>   0x010101, , , 0xFFF402, 0xFFF402, , , 0xFDCE00, 0xFCFDED, , ,
>   0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, 0xFFF402, 0x653700, , 0xFDCE00, , , , 0xFFF402,
>   , 0x1B1B1B, , 0xFDCE00, 0xFDCE00, , , , 0xFFF402, 0x020202, ,
>   0xFFFA73, , 0xFDCE00, 0xFDCE00, , 0xFFF402, 0xFFF402, , , , 0xFFFA73,
>   0xF09F00, , , 0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, , , , 0x613500, , 0xFFF402,
>   0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, 0x653700, , , 0x0F0F0F, 0xFDCE00, , , , ,
>   0xFFF402, 0xFFF402, , 0x653700, 0xFDCE00, 0xFDCE00, , , , 0xFFF402, ,
>   , 0xFDCE00, , 0xFFF402, 0x653700, , , , 0xFDCE00, , 0xF09F00, ,
>   0xFDCE00, , 0x000000, , 0xFDCE00, , , 0xFDCE00, , , , 0xFFF402,
>   0xFDCE00, , 0xF09F00, 0xFDCE00, 0xFDCE00, 0x140100, , , , , 0x653700,
>   , , , , , 0xFDCE00, , 0xFFFA73, , 0xF09F00, 0x171717, 0xB65B00, , ,
>   0xB65B00, , , 0xFFF402, , 0xF09F00, 0xFDCE00, 0xB65B00, , , , ,
>   0xB65B00, , , 0xF09F00, 0x653700, , , 0xFDCE00, , , , 0x140100, , , ,
>   0x653700, , 0x140100, 0xFFFA73, , 0xFFF402, 0xFDCE00, , 0xFEFBA4, , ,
>   , 0xFFFA73, , , , , , 0xFDCE00, 0xFFFA73, 0xFDCE00, , , , 0xFFFA73, ,
>   , 0xFFFA73, 0xFFFA73, , , 0x653700, , 0xFDCE00, 0xFFF402, , 0xFFFA73,
>   , , , , , 0xFFFA73, , 0xFFF402, , 0xFFFA73, , 0xFDCE00, , , , ,
>   0xFFF402, , , , , , , 0xFDCE00, , 0x653700, 0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, , ,
>   0xFFF402, 0xFFF402, 0xFDCE00, , , , , , 0xFDCE00, , 0xFDCE00, , , , ,
>   , 0xFFF402, , , 0xFDCE00, 0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, , 0xFFF402, 0x653700,
>   , , 0xFDCE00, , , , , , , 0xFDCE00, 0xF09F00, , , , 0xFDCE00, , ,
>   0xFDCE00, 0xFDCE00, , 0xFDCE00, , , , , , , 0xFFF402, 0xFDCE00, ,
>   0x653700, , , , 0xFDCE00, , , , 0xFDCE00, , 0xFDCE00, , , , 0xFDCE00,
>   , , 0xFDCE00, , , , , , , 0xFDCE00, , 0xFFF402, , , 0xFDCE00, ,
>   0x653700, 0xFDCE00, 0xFDCE00, , , 0xF09F00, , , , , , , , 0xFDCE00, ,
>   , , , , 0xFDCE00, , , , 0xFDCE00, 0xFFF402, 0xFDCE00, , , , , ,
>   0x653700, , 0xFDCE00, , , , , , , 0xF09F00, , , 0xFDCE00, , 0xF09F00,
>   , , 0xF09F00, 0xF09F00, , , , 0xFFF402, , , , , , , , 0xFDCE00,
>   0x653700, , , , , 0xFDCE00, , , , 0xF09F00, , 0x653700, , , , , , , ,
>   , 0xFFF402, , , , , , , 0xFDCE00, , , , 0x030303, 0xF09F00, , ,
>   0xF09F00, 0xF09F00, , , , , 0x653700, , , , , , , , 0xFDCE00, , , , ,
>   , 0xFFF402, , , , 0xFDCE00, , 0xFDCE00, 0x030303, , , , , , , , ,
>   0x653700, , , , , , , 0x653700, , , , , 0xF09F00, , , 0xF09F00,
>   0xF09F00, , , , , , 0x060606, , , , , , , , 0x0F0F0F, , , , , ,
>   0x653700, , , , 0x472600, , 0x653700, , , , , , , , , , , 0x010101, ,
>   , , , , , 0x000000, , , , , 0x010101, , , 0x020202, 0x040404, , , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , 0x010101, , , , , , 0x010101, , , , 0x000000, ,
>   0x010101, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 0x020202, , , , ,
>   0x020202, , , 0x010101, 0x010101, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
>   , , , 0x020202, , , , 0x010101, , 0x010101, , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , 0x000000, , , 0x000000, 0x000000, , , , , , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 0x000000, , 0x000000, , , , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 0x000000, 0x000000, , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 0x000000, , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 0x000000, , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,

The **LCD Image Converter** conversion (24 bit):

```
0x070707, 0x000000, 0x010101, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x020202, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x030303, 0x080808, 0x4d2a00, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x101010, 0x020202, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 
0x000000, 0x050505, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x020202, 0x010101, 0x030303, 0x020202, 0x0b0b0b, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0xfefba4, 0xfcfded, 0xfcfded, 0xfcfded, 0xfcfded, 0xfefba4, 0xfcfded, 0xfefba4, 0xfcfded, 0xf09f00, 0x653700, 0x613500, 0x101010, 0x020202, 0x030303, 0x010101, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 
0x040404, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x020202, 0x020202, 0x000000, 0x0a0a0a, 0x633600, 0x653700, 0xfefba4, 0xfcfded, 0xfcfded, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xf09f00, 0x653700, 0x633600, 0x050505, 0x000000, 0x010101, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 
0x000000, 0x000000, 0x010101, 0x050505, 0x010101, 0x131313, 0x653700, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfcfded, 0xfcfded, 0xf09f00, 0x140100, 0xf09f00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xf09f00, 0x140100, 0xf09f00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0x653700, 0x0d0d0d, 0x000000, 0x010101, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 
0x000000, 0x000000, 0x020202, 0x010101, 0x0a0a0a, 0x653700, 0xfffa73, 0xfcfded, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0x643700, 0x090909, 0x010101, 0x010101, 0x000000, 0x000000, 
0x000000, 0x010101, 0x010101, 0x040404, 0x653700, 0xfcfded, 0xfcfded, 0xfcfded, 0xfefba4, 0xfcfded, 0xfefba4, 0x140100, 0xfcfded, 0x140100, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0x140100, 0xfcfded, 0x140100, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0x653700, 0x0d0d0d, 0x010101, 0x000000, 0x000000, 
0x020202, 0x000000, 0x101010, 0x653700, 0xfefba4, 0xfcfded, 0xfcfded, 0xfefba4, 0xfcfded, 0xfcfded, 0xfefba4, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0x653700, 0x111111, 0x010101, 0x000000, 
0x040404, 0x0e0e0e, 0x653700, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfcfded, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0x613500, 0x020202, 0x010101, 
0x030303, 0x161616, 0x653700, 0xfcfded, 0xfcfded, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0x653700, 0x1b1b1b, 0x020202, 
0x000000, 0x653700, 0xfefba4, 0xfcfded, 0xfffa73, 0xfcfded, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0x140100, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0x140100, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfcfded, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0x613500, 0x0f0f0f, 
0x030303, 0x653700, 0xfcfded, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0x653700, 0x000000, 
0x653700, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0x653700, 0x171717, 
0x653700, 0xfcfded, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfffa73, 0x653700, 0xb65b00, 0xb65b00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xb65b00, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0xfffa73, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xf09f00, 0x653700, 
0x653700, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfffa73, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0xfffa73, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0x653700, 
0x653700, 0xfcfded, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0x653700, 0xf09f00, 0x140100, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xf09f00, 0x140100, 0xf09f00, 0x653700, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0x653700, 
0x653700, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xf09f00, 0xfff402, 0x653700, 0xb65b00, 0xf09f00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xb65b00, 0x653700, 0xfffa73, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0x653700, 
0x653700, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0x140100, 0xb65b00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xb65b00, 0x140100, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0x653700, 
0x653700, 0xfcfded, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0x140100, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xb65b00, 0x140100, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0x653700, 
0x653700, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0x653700, 0x140100, 0xb65b00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xb65b00, 0x140100, 0x653700, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0x653700, 
0x653700, 0xfdce00, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfefba4, 0x653700, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x140100, 0x653700, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0x653700, 
0x653700, 0xf09f00, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0x653700, 0x030303, 
0x171717, 0x653700, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfffa73, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfefba4, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfffa73, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0x653700, 0x030303, 
0x040404, 0x653700, 0xf09f00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0x653700, 0x060606, 
0x020202, 0x030303, 0x653700, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xfff402, 0x653700, 0x0f0f0f, 0x010101, 
0x050505, 0x020202, 0x653700, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0x653700, 0x000000, 0x010101, 
0x050505, 0x030303, 0x141414, 0x653700, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0x472600, 0x010101, 0x010101, 0x020202, 
0x090909, 0x040404, 0x010101, 0x030303, 0x653700, 0xf09f00, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xf09f00, 0x653700, 0x020202, 0x000000, 0x020202, 0x020202, 
0x060606, 0x030303, 0x010101, 0x020202, 0x090909, 0x643600, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0x653700, 0x040404, 0x010101, 0x010101, 0x010101, 0x000000, 
0x000000, 0x020202, 0x000000, 0x010101, 0x010101, 0x0b0b0b, 0x653700, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfff402, 0xf09f00, 0xee9e00, 0x5b3200, 0x0a0a0a, 0x000000, 0x010101, 0x010101, 0x000000, 0x000000, 
0x010101, 0x000000, 0x010101, 0x000000, 0x010101, 0x020202, 0x0d0d0d, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0x5e3300, 0x0a0a0a, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 
0x000000, 0x010101, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x010101, 0x020202, 0x0c0c0c, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0xf09f00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xfdce00, 0xf09f00, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x080808, 0x000000, 0x020202, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 
0x070707, 0x050505, 0x010101, 0x030303, 0x010101, 0x000000, 0x020202, 0x020202, 0x0d0d0d, 0x010101, 0x020202, 0x080808, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x653700, 0x5b3200, 0x020202, 0x010101, 0x010101, 0x010101, 0x010101, 0x010101, 0x010101, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000
```

Comment: Right! I didn't notice it thank you. I'm experimenting the code and I forgot to change it.

Comment: We you see empty strings back then you can figure out that `arrayImage[i * j]` is not correct.  Always best to test the code first with very small images so you can figure out what is *supposed* to happen while stepping through the code with the debugger.  Use `[i + j * image.Width]` instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'll try to test it out but can I ask why I will use ``[i + j * image.Width]``?

Comment: You probably haven't yet thought enough about how you map a two-dimensional grid of values to a one-dimensional array.  Use paper and pen, start by drawing a 3 x 2 grid.

Comment: You are so awesome! I change it to ``[i + j * image.Width]`` and ITS WORKING thank you soo muuch. I really thought about it that it is like that. It is for our thesis project and you save me from this. Thank you so much man

Comment: Also I want to ask again. If you have frames of bitmap. Is it ``[i + j * image.Width * frames]`` is it like this? I've been thinking thoroughly and I don't quite get the 3-dimensional array into one-dimensional array